# Sink method for non-matched JAX-RS requests

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

Is is it possible to configure JAX-RS to call certain method to process all requests that doesn't match any other resource methods (because of e.g. non-matching `@Path`).

My naive approach:

```java
@Path("/")
public class RootResource {

    @GET
    @Path("foo")
    public String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{x: .*}")
    public String sink(@PathParam("x") String path) {
        return "Unknown path: " + path;
    }
}
```

works yet it print warning: `RESTEASY002142: Multiple resource methods match request "GET /foo". Selecting one. Matching methods: [public java.lang.String restresources.RootResource.sink(java.lang.String), public java.lang.String restresources.RootResource.foo()]`

Answer (score 1):

§3.7.2 **Request Matching** in the [JAX-RS 2.0 Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr339/index.html) has rather a lot to say about matching request URIs to handlers.

In a couple of places it says:

> ... implementations SHOULD report a warning and select one of these methods in an implementation dependent manner.

So it looks like you have encountered this condition.

Therefore you need to go through the rules in the spec to see how you can specify the fall through condition that you want.